# Global style and local style overriding global style under same control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, wpf-style

I have a global style declared for TypeMenu Item like this in a DefaultTheme.xaml file

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    .
    .
    .
</Style>
```

Merged it to the User control

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary  Source="../DefaultTheme.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Now in the user control If i declare any style for of `TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}"` it inherits the styles declared from global style.

E.g.

```
<Style  x:Key="LocalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    .
    .
    .
</Style>
```

This would have the global style applied as well. I dont want this local style to inherit the global style. So I can override this by giving `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">..</Style>` in my usercontrol.

Here is the catch, If I do this i will not be able to apply the global style to other places in the control because I have locally overridden this. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Style Inheritance](http://wpftutorial.net/StyleInheritance.html), your narration is something reverse. Since the local style was not inherited from the base, so the base style will not be applied for the local.

`If I do this i will not be able to apply the global style to other places in the control because I have locally overridden this`

This will not happen, Since the local style was declared with a key and it will apply to the `MenuItem` where the key is referenced. Rest all are applied with the global style.